# Open file for writing from shared lib written in C in Solaris

Tags: c, gcc, file-io, shared-libraries, solaris

I need to append information into a given file from a shared lib I wrote in C in Solaris. What would be the safest way to open the file in a shared way for writing ? Being a shared lib I assume there's a risk two instances try to write to the file simultaneously.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two processes writing to the same file will, sooner or later, result in a garbled file. If you have access to both the library (which it seems you do) and the application, then you can protect all writes to the file with `flock` calls.

Comment: Don't forget that `fwrite` buffers data. To be totally safe you should follow every write call with `fflush` or make sure that the file descriptor is in line buffer mode.